# Where to put resource file in web application

Tags: c#, enums, resources, poco

I am using resource file to manage strings to show in UI. I have requirement to show enum values to UI.

Definitely I can do it with [Display] attribute to achieve this. However i have common project for POCOs where i create Enums as well and to use display attribute, i would require to take resource project's reference in that POCOs project.

This causes resource file gets copied in every other projects who uses that POCOs including WCFs where it is not requried.

Any suggestion to achieve Displaying ENUM from Resource file but not let other projects to build Resource file DLL?

Comment: you can add the resource to a (shared) dll and on the properties of the file, set Build action to Embedded Resource. The file is embedded in the dll which you can access and apply interfacing with

Comment: I don't want to add resource file's reference in POCO because it gets copied to every project which uses POCOs(although as Embeded).